# How to define a path in podspec file from neighbor's folder for propertys?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, path, cocoapods

React Native app with the next structure:

```
root
  |- ios
      |- Pods
      |   |- ChartFramework
      |- Podfile
  |- node_modules
      |- react-native-library
          |- react-native-library.podspec
```

How to define the path for public_header_files/vendored_frameworks propertys in react-native-library.podspec from root/ios/Pods/ChartFramework?

1.Put relative path:

***react-native-library.podspec***

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name           = name
    s.version        = version
    s.description    = description
    s.summary        = summary
    s.homepage       = homepage
    s.license        = license
    s.authors        = authors
    s.source = { :http => "file://#{zipfile}"}
    s.platform     = :ios, "9.0"
    s.public_header_files = "../../ios/Pods/ChartFramework/ChartFramework.frameworks/Headers/*"
    s.vendored_frameworks = "../../ios/Pods/ChartFramework/ChartFramework.framework"
    s.dependency "React"
end
```

In this case after build in Xcode get the error:

```
'ChartFramework/ChartFramework.h' file not found
```

2.Put relative paths like an object:

***react-native-library.podspec***

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name           = name
    s.version        = version
    s.description    = description
    s.summary        = summary
    s.homepage       = homepage
    s.license        = license
    s.authors        = authors
    s.source = { :http => "file://#{zipfile}"}
    s.platform     = :ios, "9.0"
    s.public_header_files = { :path => "../../ios/Pods/ChartFramework/ChartFramework.frameworks/Headers/*" }
    s.vendored_frameworks = { :path => "../../ios/Pods/ChartFramework/ChartFramework.framework" }
    s.dependency "React"
end
```

But in this case get the error after pod install:

[image]

Any ideas how to write the correct path for ChartFramework from root/node_modules/react-native-library/react-native-library.podspec?

Answer (score 0):

I found that

When I run

```
pod lib lint
```

The relative path is from .podspec file.

When I run

```
pod repo push
```

The relative path is from the root of the `s.source` file.